# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n< \infty $ imply $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} n a_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ \{a_n\} \ n \in \mathbb{N} $ a sequence of non-negative real numbers.

Prove that
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n< \infty $ imply $\displaystyle\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n \leq N} n a_n=0$

Would this be accomplished without the condition $a_n \geq 0$?

Comment: Hint: note that the series $s_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n = a_1+\cdot+a_N$ is always an upper bound of $\sum_{n=1}^N na_n=1/Na_1+2/Na_2+\cdot+a_N$.

Answer (score 4):

You can prove this with Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. I'll prove it in a different setting, and I'll let you adapt the proof. Suppose that $g\in L^1_+[0,\infty)$. Then $$\frac 1n \int_0^n xg(x)dx\to 0$$ as $n\to\infty$.

*Proof* Consider $g_n(x)= \dfrac{xg(x)}n {\bf 1}_{[0,n]}$. Then $|g_n|\leqslant |g|$ and $g_n(x)\to 0$. By DCT, we conclude.

Comment: I'll read about DCT, I I don't heard before

Comment: I will try to reproduce. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$ be the partial sum of $\{a_n\}$, by [summation by parts formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Statement)
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N na_n = \sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1}A_n(n - (n + 1)) + NA_N = NA_N - \sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1}A_n.$$
Thus, based on the famous [Cesaro's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation#Definition)
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^N na_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} A_N - \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1}A_n}{N} = a - a = 0$$
where $a = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n < \infty$.

The above proof shows that as long as $\left|\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n\right| < \infty$, the result always holds. $a_n$ could be negative.

Comment: I' ll copy this Proof

Comment: I will try to reproduce. Thanks

Comment: How do you dervive $\lim_{N\to\infty}(\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}A_n)/N=a$? (Not saying that it's not correct, but that that is a non-trivial result in its own right.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation. I would assume this result is so famous that every math student would know that.

Comment: "The above proof shows that as long as $|\sum a_n|<\infty$" I think you want to say "as long as $\sum a_n$ converges"

Comment: At the level this question is given I think it is safe to assume that the students have *not* been exposed to this result yet and that the problem 'is meant' to be solved by elementary means ($\epsilon-N$). However, it is always hard to answer questions without knowing what one is allowed to assume so this answer is perfectly fine:)

Comment: @zhw Yes, that's what I meant. I want to stress that $\sum a_n = -\infty$ is not allowed.

Comment: @Winther All right, maybe I should at least mention it in the answer (I tried not being distractive). Based on my own experience, immediately after learning the $\varepsilon-N$ language, we were asked to prove that if $a_n \to a \in \mathbb{R}$ as $n \to \infty$, then its arithmetic average $(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)/n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: You might be right about that, it's 12 years since I did my calculus so it's a good chance I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

$\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N na_n}{N}=\dfrac{a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots +Na_N}{N}=\dfrac{a_1+\cdots+a_N}{N}+\dfrac{N-1}{N}\cdot\dfrac{a_2+\cdots+a_N}{N-1}+\cdots + \dfrac{a_N}{N}\to 0+0+\cdots + 0 = 0$ by the well-known Cesaro's theorem as $a_N \to 0$ when $N \to \infty$ since the first series converges imply the general terms tend to $0$. The result still holds without $a_n \geq 0$.

Comment: Each summand tends to zero, but the count of summands is arbitrarily large, so this proof doesn't stand

Comment: I will try to reproduce. Thanks

Comment: If that was a valid argument we could also say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2n} = 0 + 0 + \ldots + 0 = 0$ while the true result is $\log(2)$.